# Why does this usage of inline lead to a compilation error in F#?

Tags: f#

I am trying to learn more about `inline` and SRTP. Unfortunately I don't have the understanding to make this sample more minimal, but it's not too big:

```ml
type ComponentCollection<'props, 'comp when 'props : comparison> =
  {
    Components : Map<'props, 'comp>
  }
  with
    static member AddComponent (collection, props, comp) =
      {
        Components =
          collection.Components
          |> Map.add props comp
      }

module ComponentCollection =

  let inline add< ^t, ^props, ^comp 
                 when ^t : (static member AddComponent : ((^t * ^props * ^comp) -> ^t)) > 
                 (props : ^props) (comp : ^comp) (xs : ^t) =
    (^t : (static member AddComponent : (^t * ^props * ^comp -> ^t ) ) () ) (xs, props, comp)

type Component<'t> =
  {
    Props : 't
  }

type Foo =
  {
    Foo : int
  }

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =

  let foo = { Foo = 1 }

  let a : ComponentCollection<Foo, Component<Foo>> =
    { Components = Map.empty }
    |> ComponentCollection.add foo { Props = foo }

  0
```

The gives a compilation error:

> error FS0001: The type 'ComponentCollection<'a,'b>' does not support the operator 'get_AddComponent'

This is very misleading to me, since I am using `static member AddComponent`, not `get_AddComponent`. I am not sure where the compiler gets `get_AddComponent` from.

**What am I doing wrong here?**

Additionally, it would be very helpful if someone could explain this bit of the code:

```ml
  (^t : (static member AddComponent : (^t * ^props * ^comp -> ^t ) ) () )
```

I understand that it somehow provides the `static` member `AddComponent` of `^t` as a free-function, but I cobbled it together from other examples, and the documentation for this syntax is lacking. For example, why is a `()` required?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see, the only thing that is wrong with your snippet is that you have some excessive parentheses which, unfortunately in this case, actually have semantic meaning. Changing the code as follows resolves the problem:

```ml
module ComponentCollection =
  let inline add< ^t, ^props, ^comp 
                 when ^t : (static member AddComponent : ^t * ^props * ^comp -> ^t) > 
                 (props : ^props) (comp : ^comp) (xs : ^t) =
    (^t : (static member AddComponent : ^t * ^props * ^comp -> ^t) (xs, props, comp))
```

The issue is that F# actually makes a difference between:

```
static member AddComponent : ^t * ^props * ^comp -> ^t
static member AddComponent : (^t * ^props * ^comp) -> ^t
static member AddComponent : ((^t * ^props * ^comp) -> ^t)
```

- The first is a regular static method with three arguments
- The second is a static method taking three-element tuple as a single argument
- The last is a static property returning a function value taking a tuple

Regarding your second question - in the working version, the call looks like this:

```
(^t : (static member AddComponent : ^t * ^props * ^comp -> ^t) (xs, props, comp))
```

This tells the compiler to access the static member (which is required by the constraint) and invoke it with arguments `xs`, `props` and `comp`. In your original version, this was invoking a getter method of the property (confusingly though, it somehow allowed you to do this without arguments - I suspect this would lead to another type error later).

Answer (score 2):

From experience, SRTP's are complex and hard to use. They require a lot of `inline`s and Error messages tend to be very obscure.

I would recommend limiting their use.
Also, they would not be C# compatible if that is something you are interested in.

I also changed your code to fix the issues:

```
type ComponentCollection<'props, 'comp when 'props : comparison> =
{
    Components : Map<'props, 'comp>
}
with
    member collection.AddComponent(props, comp) =
    {
        Components =
        collection.Components
        |> Map.add props comp
    }

module ComponentCollection =

let inline add< ^t, ^props, ^comp 
                when 'props : comparison and ^t : (member AddComponent : ^props * ^comp -> ^t) > 
                (props : ^props) (comp : ^comp) (xs : ^t) =
    (^t : (member AddComponent : ^props * ^comp -> ^t ) (xs, props, comp ))

type Component<'t> =
{
    Props : 't
}

type Foo =
{
    Foo : int
}

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =

    let foo = { Foo = 1 }

    let a  =
        { Components = Map.empty } 
        |> ComponentCollection.add foo { Props = foo }

    0
```